# Cordova - Saving/ Downloading a backup JSON file that is dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am building an HTML5 phonegap application. This app exports data so that the user can backup and restore any time. I'm doing this exporting with the following javascript code:

```
    var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.data, null, "\t"));
    var dlAnchorElem = document.createElement('a');
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", "data.json");
    document.body.appendChild(dlAnchorElem);
    dlAnchorElem.click();
```

This generates an anchor tag with an encoded file and clicks so it downloads. Works great on browser, but does nothing in a compiled Cordova application.

After doing some research, I found that the default solution would be to use a download plugin for Cordova, specifically this one: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

I read the documentation, but it does not seem to take an encoded file as parameter, but an encoded URL for download. Also, it takes the save path on the phone, which I prefer would just default to the download folder.

My question is: What is the best way to achieve this, considering I'm dynamically generating the JSON backup file. Is there perhaps an AndroidManifest directive that allows for file downloads?

Comment: Usually, for app where you can store data server side, you should have a SQL DB onto the server and a local SQLite DB into the app. You can sync both DBs on an user action or even automatically. Is this your case?

Answer (score 1):

After some research and trying many different hacks, I came to the conclusion that it's currently not allowed natively with cordova or with the available plugins. My solution was to, instead of writing to the filesystem, use the web share api to let the user export the way he finds best (including file, if he chooses dropbox, onedrive or google drive).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally found this cordova plugin which looks like to work on android !
https://github.com/Amphiluke/cordova-plugin-save-dialog

(I didn't succeed to use share api on android )